# Angular USES *ngFor for mouseenter and mouseleave residues in multiple li

Tags: javascript, angular, html-lists, ngfor

[image]

Angular USES *ngFor for mouseenter and mouseleave residues in multiple li,I don't know what is the cause of this, please help me, thank you。

The front-end USES angular framework, mouseenter,mouseleave on *ngFor generation of multiple li, fast sliding when multiple display background color, I tried to replace mouseover mouseout, but not

```
  <ul>
 <li class="file-list-item" *ngFor="let file of searchService.fileLists;let i = index"                                (mouseenter)="file.hoverVisual=true;unfoldItem=false" (mouseleave)="file.hoverVisual=false;unfoldItem=false"
 fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
  <div class="item-title-big" *ngIf="!file.isshowTitle" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
   <div class="panel-checkbox" #chbox>
...
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to show only one change in li when I swipe multiple times, but I want to show more than two changes in li when I swipe quickly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Is it possible to develop a small example of your issue using stackblitz.com? It may be easier for others to then help you.